# Simple relation in YII, can't get it done

Tags: yii, relationship, relation

This is the first time I use relations in Yii, the question is very simple.

```
MODULE TABLE

name - PK
status - FK status_id

STATUS TABLE

id PK
name
```

So, each Module HAS one status.

But I can not seem to get it working.

Module.php (Model)

```
public function relations()
  {
    return array(
      'status'=>array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'ModuleStatus', 'status'),
    );
  }
```

I access them this way:

```
$modulesAR = Module::model()->with('status')->findAll();
    if( $modulesAR )
    {
      foreach( $modulesAR as $moduleAR )
      {
        $this->modules[ $moduleAR->name ] = array(
          'sessionLimit' => isset($moduleAR->sessionLimit) ? $moduleAR->sessionLimit : 0,
          'status' => isset($moduleAR->status) ? $moduleAR->status : 'disabled',
        );
      }
    }
```

Var_dump(Yii::app()->module->modules;

```
array(3) {
  ["digidoc"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["sessionLimit"]=>
    int(0)
    ["status"]=>
    string(1) "2" // Should say "Disabled"
  }
  ["docusearch"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["sessionLimit"]=>
    int(0)
    ["status"]=>
    string(1) "1" // Should say "Enabled"
  }
  ["printbox"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["sessionLimit"]=>
    int(0)
    ["status"]=>
    string(1) "2" // Should say "Disabled"
  }
}
```

I will appreciate any help.

Thanks!

EDIT:

query executed by Yii:

```
SELECT `t`.`name` AS `t0_c0`, `t`.`status_id` AS `t0_c1`, `t`.`session_limit` AS `t0_c2`, `status`.`id` AS `t1_c0`, `status`.`name` AS `t1_c1` FROM `ss_module` `t`  LEFT OUTER JOIN `ss_module_status` `status` ON (`status`.`id`=`t`.`name`)

+------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| t0_c0      | t0_c1 | t0_c2 | t1_c0 | t1_c1 |
+------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| digidoc    |     2 |     0 |  NULL | NULL  |
| docusearch |     1 |     2 |  NULL | NULL  |
| printbox   |     2 |     0 |  NULL | NULL  |
+------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

EDIT 2:

Changing the last

```
ON (`status`.`id`=`t`.`name`);
```

to

```
ON (`status`.`id`=`t`.`status_id`);
```

works as expected, by I dont know how to fix it in Yii.

Comment: Your model has a property called `status` *and* a relation named `status`.The property will take precedence. Give your relation a different name. (And then access its `name` property to get the actual "Disabled" string.)

Comment: Ok I changed it to status_name in the relation and in with() with var_dumping it gives NULL, any ideas?

Comment: Enable [query logging](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10629728/yii-how-to-print-sql-used-by-findall/10629915#10629915), look at the generated DB query. If the query is correct, step over the code in a debugger...

Comment: I've updated the question with the query, in MySQL Console it doesn't retrieve the statuses names.

Comment: @DCoder I am almost there, found the change needed in the query but I dont know what to change in Yii

Comment: Are you sure your relation is specified as `self::BELONGS_TO`? It seems to me that you might have changed it when you were fixing the property/relation name collision.

Comment: Thanks! It was that, I modified it to HAS_ONE but I crearly don't understand what refers to what. I was thinking of 'module_status(self::HAS_ONE,'id')' like that A MODULE HAS ONE STATUS. You can put the answer if you want.

Answer (score 0):

When you peek into `$moduleAR->status`, you get the whole Status model instance, not it's id. So just go on and peek into that instance:

`$moduleAR->status->name`.

That's what ActiveRecord magic is intended for ;)

And inversely, if you have Status model, you should have a relation there saying something like this:

`'modules' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Module', 'status_id')`

Which could make the following possible:

```
$status = Status::model()->find(/*somehow*/);
/* now that $status is an Status instance */
foreach ($status->modules as $module) {
  // here you are! looping over all modules connected to this status
  // each $module is a full-fledged Module instance
}
```