# Yii - CDbCriteria unexpected results

Tags: database, yii, frameworks

I am doing what looks like a simple query basically doing a WHERE clause on the competition_id and the prize_type

```
    $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
    $criteria->select = 't.*, myuser.firstname, myuser.surname';
    $criteria->join ='LEFT JOIN myuser ON myuser.user_id = t.user_id';
    $criteria->condition = 't.competition_id = :competition_id';
    $criteria->condition = 't.prize_type = :prize_type';
    $criteria->params = array(":competition_id" => $competition_id);
    $criteria->params = array(":prize_type" => "1");

    $winners = CompetitionWinners::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

Can anyone suggest what is wrong with my code... I am expecting around 4 rows.. but get over 600?

I just want to do ...

```
WHERE competition_id = 123 AND prize_type = 1;
```

Is there a simple function to simply output the SQL query for this SINGLE CDbCriteria 'event'?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10629728/yii-how-to-print-sql-used-by-findall and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4435886/yii-model-to-array/4577768#4577768 can help you to debug queries

Comment: Can anyone explain why this would be downvoted for - a day after an answer has been accepted? It does ruin the community somewhat when it happens and not a single reason is given..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria;
    $criteria->select = 't.*, myuser.firstname, myuser.surname';
    $criteria->join ='LEFT JOIN myuser ON myuser.user_id = t.user_id';
    $criteria->condition = 't.competition_id = :competition_id AND t.prize_type = :prize_type';
    $criteria->params = array(":competition_id" => $competition_id,":prize_type" => "1");
    $winners = CompetitionWinners::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

Comment: great! is there way to get Yii to output this criteria as an SQL string for debugging purposes? I can get Yii to output everything but its tricky when there are so many others queries on the page.

Comment: hehehhe....I am afraid i do not know any other way.. i also use the same tricky way for finding the executed queries :)

Comment: accepted thanks again! Yii really need some form of criteria->outputQuery() :P

Answer (score 1):

Or you could use [CDbCriteria::addCondition()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria#addCondition-detail)

```
$criteria->addCondition('t.competition_id = :competition_id')
         ->addCondition('t.prize_type = :prize_type');
```